# Unique trace for C*-algebras

Tags: c-star-algebras, trace

Prove that UHF algebra has a unique trace, how about AF C*-algebras?

Does any special meaning for a C*-algebra has a unique trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace space of even a simple AF algebra can be literally anything (*i.e.* a metrisable Choquet simplex) as shown by Blackadar

> B. Blackadar, Traces on simple AF C*-algebras. *J. Funct. Anal.* **38** (1980), no. 2, 156–168.

It is also easy to see that for each totally disconnected compact space $K$ (*e.g.* the Cantor set), the commutative algebra $C(K)$ is AF and it has lots of traces because it has lots of characters!

As for your first question, note that every UHF algebra $A$ arises as a direct limit of full matrix algebras $(M_{n_k}, \varphi_k)$, where the connecting maps $\varphi_k$ are unital. Consequently, every trace on $A$ restricts to a (unique) trace on $M_{n_k}$. Because the union of $M_{n_k}$ is dense in $A$, the trace on $A$ is unique.

Comment: as shown by [Blackadar (1980) and, independently, by Goodearl (1977/1978)](http://books.google.ca/books?id=214a1Wri63QC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=goodearl+traces+blackadar&source=bl&ots=S906llH-Ki&sig=zdDEKzvJWj_8aSQKzkX7L_w_TF0&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=pmKeUqO0HpKIqQHDnoHoBw&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=goodearl%20traces%20blackadar&f=false).